# Node.js: How to set npm start?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I tried to use `npm start` to start my application. So I added the following line in my package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
```

however, when I used `npm start`, I met with this problem:
[image]

but when I used `node app.js`, it worked. So what's the problem?

Comment: Can you include the content of your package.json for the application name?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the errors at the top of your screenshot?

Comment: Solved, I forgot to open my database. Your advice is really helpful, because the problem lies in the top of my screen shot, which I didn't include in the image, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `npm run start` instead of `npm start`.